# Getting Specific data from Nested Json which is having multiple Parent Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Am trying to filter out some specific data's from Nested JSON which is having multiple Parent Children . Here is my json ,

```js
[{
  "id": "111111",
  "name": "Parent",
  "steps": [{
    "id": "22222",
    "name": "Child",
    "steps": [{
      "id": "333333",
      "name": "Child -Child",
      "steps": [{
        "id": "444444",
        "name": "Child - Child - Child",
        "steps": [{
          "id": "5555",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child"
        }, {
          "id": "522e9327-0747-4080-b6e2-d57e726b5b26",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child 2"
        }],

      }],

    }],

  }],
}]
```

What am trying to do here is i have to get some specific data's which are inside this nested json . For Ex : i need output like `["parent","Child","Child-Child"...etc ]` . So i used map function using java script but the output was different like this one `["ParentChildChildChild"]` (With No spaces) .If output's are String only mean's i can put "\n" and separate them but sometimes they are in Numbers so problem will occur's . Here is my Code which i tried ,

```js
var myReturnedValues = mainSteps.map(x => [
  x.steps.map(y => y.name + 
    y.steps.map(z => z.name + 
      z.steps.map(a => a.name + a.steps.map(b => b.name))
    )
  )
]);
```

Can someone help/clarify Me .

Comment: you can use underscore flatten function in recursively

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this most effectively you need To achieve this most effectively you need To achieve this most effectively you need to use recursion use recursion use recursion.

Using this pattern means that the array will always be filled no matter how many levels of nested object you have. Try this:

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "111111",
  "name": "Parent",
  "steps": [{
    "id": "22222",
    "name": "Child",
    "steps": [{
      "id": "333333",
      "name": "Child -Child",
      "steps": [{
        "id": "444444",
        "name": "Child - Child - Child",
        "steps": [{
          "id": "5555",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child"
        }, {
          "id": "522e9327-0747-4080-b6e2-d57e726b5b26",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child 2"
        }],

      }],

    }],

  }],
}]

var names = [];
function getNames(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        names.push(arr[i].name);
        if (arr[i].steps && arr[i].steps.length)
            getNames(arr[i].steps);
    }
}

getNames(data);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan , Thanks mam..It works for me But one new problem arised !!! Can edit my question and update my problem with explanation ?

Comment: Sure, although if it's a separate issue it may be worth starting a new question completely

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the javascript map function & recursion

```
var jsonArray = [{
  "id": "111111",
  "name": "Parent",
  "steps": [{
    "id": "22222",
    "name": "Child",
    "steps": [{
      "id": "333333",
      "name": "Child -Child",
      "steps": [{
        "id": "444444",
        "name": "Child - Child - Child",
        "steps": [{
          "id": "5555",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child"
        }, {
          "id": "522e9327-0747-4080-b6e2-d57e726b5b26",
          "name": "Child - Child - Child - Child 2"
        }],

      }],

    }],

  }],
}]

var namesArray = [];
var recur = function(obj) {
  namesArray.push(obj.name);
  if(obj.steps) {
    obj.steps.map(recur);
  }
}

jsonArray.map(recur);
console.log(namesArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
function getObjectKeyValues(obj, objKey) { 
    var result = []; 
    JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) { 
        if (key === objKey) { 
            result.push(value) 
        }
        return;
    }); 
    return result;
}
```

Check:

[MDN JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)